# Pass a type as function parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

It is possible to pass a `type` as function parameter?

I would like to do something like:

```
type TYPE_A = {};     

function foo(paramAsType) { 
  if (paramAsype is TYPE_A) {
    // do stuff
  }
  else {
    // do other stuff 
  }
}
```

If this way is wrong, there is a method to do that using the generic type?

Comment: Have a look at type predicates https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: No. Types (specified by `type`) do not exist in JavaScript, which is what TypeScript compiles to, and what is actually run. You can pass an object of a particular type and check its type (which is what your example code would do), but that is different from passing a type as a real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not exactly clear what you are asking. But this is how to pass a generic type and check the type of the passed generic against an existing custom type.

```
type TYPE_A = {};  
function food<CustomType>(paramAstype: CustomType){
  if (paramAstype instanceOf TYPE_A) {
    // Then the type passed as a generic is of TYPE_A
  }
  else {
    // Then the type passed as a generic is another type 
  }
}
```